# Creating a generic polynomial from a smaller one

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Given a generic polynomial for $C_3$ extensions, $f(x,t)=x^3 - tx^2+(t-3)x+1$, I want to find a generic polynomial for $A_4$ extensions with exactly three parameters in a field of characteristic different to $2$. This problem is taken from Jensen's book on the inverse galois problem, #2.13.

My approach to this was to use Cardano's Formulas for characteristics $\neq 2,3$ to find a root $r_1$ (in fact use Sage to calculate them) of $f(x,t)$. Then, it was a previous exercise to show that if $a,b,c$ are conjugate elements in $K(r_1)$, then $K(\sqrt{ab},\sqrt{bc})$ is an $A_4$ extension over $K$. So a general element of $K(r_1)\setminus K$ would be $l_2r_1^2+l_1r_1+l_0$, with not both $l_2,l_1=0$ and $l_i\in K$. The conjugates are then just substituting the $r_1$ for the other respective roots.

Therefore finding a minimal polynomial for $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}$ over $K$ is possible and it would give me a generic polynomial for $A_4$ extensions, but the expression I get is pretty nasty, and so I don't think that's what the exercise intended me to do. Furthermore, it asks for only three parameters, while this polynomial would depend on $l_2,l_1,l_0,t$. I think it could be possible to scale the $l_i s$ to only need two of them, but I am unsure.

This is what I obtain for $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}$ in case it helps:

```
 1/18*sqrt(((2*(1/2)^(2/3)*(t^2 - 3*t + 9)*(-I*sqrt(3) + 1)/(2*t^3 -
 9*(t - 3)*t + 3*sqrt(3)*(I*t^2 - 3*I*t + 9*I) - 27)^(1/3) +
 (1/2)^(1/3)*(2*t^3 - 9*(t - 3)*t + 3*sqrt(3)*(I*t^2 - 3*I*t + 9*I) -
 27)^(1/3)*(I*sqrt(3) + 1) - 2*t)^2*r2 - 6*(2*(1/2)^(2/3)*(t^2 - 3*t +
 9)*(-I*sqrt(3) + 1)/(2*t^3 - 9*(t - 3)*t + 3*sqrt(3)*(I*t^2 - 3*I*t +
 9*I) - 27)^(1/3) + (1/2)^(1/3)*(2*t^3 - 9*(t - 3)*t + 3*sqrt(3)*(I*t^2
 - 3*I*t + 9*I) - 27)^(1/3)*(I*sqrt(3) + 1) - 2*t)*r1 + 36*r0)^2)
```

Edit: I realize that I can compute the minimal polynomial in a simpler fashion by using Galois Theory (multiplying $\prod X-\sigma(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{yz})$), but also still thinking this is not the right way since Sage is taking a long time computing and simplifying the product.